# How can I reduce the horizontal space between col-md-4 divs?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="content">1x1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="content">1x2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="content">1x3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="content">2x1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="content">2x2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="content">2x3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="content">3x1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="content">3x2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="content">3x3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
    background-color: #1A1919;
    color: white;    
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
}

.row{
    padding: 5px;  
}
```

I have managed to make vertical spaces between the columns by adding padding to the rows. But now the horizontal spaces between the contents are ways too much. How can I configure the spacing between them?

Comment: Which boostrap version are you using?

Comment: bootstrap/3.3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That *large horizontal space* is because of the `fixed width of the content class` if you remove that, you'll see it grow.
You can set the width of the content in % or add a margin to the content class.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  background-color: #1A1919;
  color: white;
  height: 400px;
}

.row{
padding:15px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col4">
      <div class="content">1x1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col4">
      <div class="content">1x2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col4">
      <div class="content">1x3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-4 col4">
      <div class="content">2x1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col4">
      <div class="content">2x2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col4">
      <div class="content">2x3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row col4 col4">
    <div class="col-md-4 col4">
      <div class="content">3x1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col4">
      <div class="content">3x2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="content">3x3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS Grid to achieve that layout you desire:**

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  width:80%;
}
.item {
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  min-height:100px;
  max-width: 350px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item">1x1</div>
  <div class="item">1x2</div>
  <div class="item">1x3</div>  
  <div class="item">2x1</div>
  <div class="item">2x2</div>
  <div class="item">2x3</div>
  <div class="item">3x1</div>
  <div class="item">3x2</div>
  <div class="item">3x3</div> 
</div>
```

**Using flexbox:**

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  /*Generates a flexbox layout with default flex direction as row */
  width: 100%;
  /* Not really required */
  align-items: center;
  /*Aligns contents vertically */
  justify-content: center;
  /*Aligns contents horizontally */
  text-align: center;
  /*Aligns further text in the center */
}

.item {
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  min-height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161463/discussion-on-answer-by-highdef-how-can-i-reduce-the-horizontal-space-between-co).

Answer (score 0):

Use **float:left;** with class **content** as below:

```css
.container {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
    float: left;
    background-color: #1A1919;
    color: white;    
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
}

.row{
    padding: 5px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="content">1x1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="content">1x2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="content">1x3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="content">2x1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="content">2x2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="content">2x3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="content">3x1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="content">3x2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="content">3x3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the use of bootstrap if you float items and that's not what the OP asked.

Comment: It wasn't clear that he was asking about bootstrap, so I edit the question now and add the bootstrap tag.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your request correctly, you are just asking how to make it look like the boxes are in the center of the page, and they are evenly spaced. see if this is what you're looking for:

```
.container {
text-align: center;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
background-color: #1A1919;
color: white;    
height: 400px;
width: 300px;
}


.col-md-4 {
margin: 5px -10px 0px -4px;;
}
```

play with the numbers until you get the desired location.

Though I would strongly suggest that you add your own class in addition to col-md-4 to the boxes, which will prevent this new setting to col-md-4 from affecting any future use of this bootstrap class.

in other words . . .

CSS:

```
.container {
text-align: center;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
background-color: #1A1919;
color: white;    
height: 400px;
width: 300px;
}


.box-move {
margin: 5px -10px 0px -4px;;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 box-move">
            <div class="content">1x1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 box-move">
            <div class="content">1x2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 box-move">
            <div class="content">1x3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 box-move">
            <div class="content">2x1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 box-move">
            <div class="content">2x2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 box-move">
            <div class="content">2x3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 box-move">
            <div class="content">3x1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 box-move">
            <div class="content">3x2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 box-move">
            <div class="content">3x3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can remove a lot of the stuff there and simplify it to make it responsive width a set margin:

```css
.contents {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 500px;
  
  margin: 20px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="contents">1x1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="contents">1x2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="contents">1x3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="contents">2x1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="contents">2x2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="contents">2x3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="contents">3x1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="contents">3x2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="contents">3x3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No I meant horizontal. So that's not the bottom but the right and left sides of the cols needs to be closer to eachother

Comment: But now the third div column shows up underneath he first

Comment: Fixed it again, that is the way I've done it here: https://codepen.io/johnpyp/pen/zprLyz

Comment: The issue is because of the fixed width of the content class. Because col-md-4 takes up 1/3 of the width, there is going to be leftover space from content div. I would recommend removing the fixed width on the content class, then adding a margin to it to make it spaced.

Comment: The content won't be at the center anymore now

Comment: I need to adjust the width without effecting the spacing. Is there no way to do that? Because I need small width and small spacing

Comment: You can use the `text-center` class on the container element to center everything inside. https://codepen.io/johnpyp/pen/zprLyz

Comment: Using bootstrap, the general design logic is with responsive design. This means that a lot of the sizes of things change in different view ports. Fixed widths are not recommended. In my example, the width of each of the contents changes while the margin stays the same.

Comment: I've added this to my post. I think this is what you were looking for.